# Finding all unique values in categorical image

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, javascript, unique-value

I'm using GEE and I would like to get all the unique values of a raster in a specific region. My raster is uploaded to EarthEngine as an `Image` and I would like to sample only the first band.

Which reducer should I use and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram()`. Its output is a `Dictionary` whose keys are all the unique values, converted to strings.

```js
var reduction = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), region);
print(reduction);

// Remove all the unnecessary reducer output structure and make a list of values.
var values = ee.Dictionary(reduction.get(image.bandNames().get(0)))
    .keys()
    .map(ee.Number.parse);
print(values);
```

[Runnable in Earth Engine Code Editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9d060805dbb21cb598db7bd941c06b8c)